# Setting up dansguardian after squid

Tags: squid, webfilter

i have setup squid which is running as a transparent proxy where http requests are sent through 176.16.1.197:8000

i would like to setup dansguardian with the above configuration of squid but i just cant seem to get it right. How can i go replacing the information above into the configuration of dansguardian?

```
# the port that DansGuardian listens to.
filterport = 8080

# the ip of the proxy (default is the loopback - i.e. this server)
proxyip = 127.0.0.1

# the port DansGuardian connects to proxy on
proxyport = 3128
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it up as a parent cache. Adapt the instructions [here](http://thefunkcorner.blogspot.com/2008/04/transparent-proxying-with-shorewall.html) for your use. It is for squid transparent proxy with a Privoxy parent but your setup is similar.

Answer (score 1):

filterip = XX.XX.XX.XX (IP of Dansguardian) if you are using a single server loopback is fine.
filterport = 8080 - port of dansguardian
proxyip = XX.XX.XX.XX (IP of the squid proxy server), if you are using a single server loopback is fine.
proxyport = 3128 - port of squid proxy server

try configuring your internet option on lan settings, and

proxy: XX.XX.XX.XX port 8080